# Terraria maximum mana achievable

Tags: terraria

I'm currently doing an Expert mode mage playthrough and I was wondering what the maximum possible mana achievable (on vanilla) is. What items should I use? What armor?

I've got maximum mana crystals, 6 accessory slots (demon heart, yay) and I can easily reforge them all to Arcane - so what accessories should I get if I'm planning on raw mana power?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Accessories:

- [Band of Starpower](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Band_of_Starpower) - +20 mana
- [Mana Regeneration Band](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mana_Regeneration_Band) - +20 mana
- [Magic Cuffs](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Magic_Cuffs) - +20 mana
- All accessories [reforged to Arcane](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Modifier) - +20 mana * 6 = +120 mana

Total: +180 mana

---

### Armor:

- [Hallowed Headgear](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hallowed_armor) - +100 mana
- [Diamond Robe](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Diamond_Robe) - +80 mana
- [Jungle Pants](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Jungle_Pants) - +20 mana

Total: +200 mana

---

### Potions:

Surprisingly, there are none to increase max mana, potions can only increase mana regen

---

### Other Effects:

- [Crystal Ball](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crystal_Ball) - +20 mana

Total: +20 mana

---

### Total of Totals:

Total bonuses: +400 mana

Max base mana: 200

**Max total mana: 600**

... except that the max mana cap is 400:

> [Including Mana boosts, the max cap is 400 Mana.](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mana#Notes)

Comment: What a wild ride with such a dissapointment at the end. This just creates a new question. What combination of max mana boosts, mana regen boosts and casting cost reductions is the best?

Comment: @Ids I was a bit excited too, until I noticed that.  And that sounds like another great question to figure out